# How to Cloud Database Cross-platform apps?

Tags: android, database, xamarin, cross-platform, desktop-application

I need some tips, something to give me a way or to brighten my mind. My app idea is a Recipe's Book app. But I imagine the following scenario: user writes recipes in PC (desktop app), and then, when going to cook, at the kitchen, read/ edit the recipes on the Mobile version. Aka the app do the same things in both platforms. The app is simple, basically the data will be text. But my problem is: I only knew how to develop native apps, both mobile or desktop, with local database. Recently I've been developing on xamarin. I'm doing well at it,  but My question is: how am I going to share this database? I would need it to be on cloud, right? So how could I be doing that? I just want to understand, not how exactly to do it, but now I dont have a clue on how to do that. And if you have a better platform to develop this idea, I accept tips

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  This question is off-topic for several different reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two things

1. Database
2. API

The database is to store the data, and the API is the way your different apps will exchange the data with the API.

[API in a nutshell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsx51.png)

For example : the desktop will talk to the API to add a recipe to the database, and form the other side the Mobile App will ask the API to get that recipe.

I advice you to start with MongoDB (free tier) and Express it's the fastest way to get started

Answer (score 0):

According to your situation I can advice you to use Firebase Real Time Database, it has all the functionality you want of updating data in real time and fetch it also faster and implementing it is not hard as you need to configure it in your project environment I can refer you to this [Page to learn more about firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database?gclid=CjwKCAiAqIKNBhAIEiwAu_ZLDqM2hcReM0SeEYZS2vF-MldUnZiToK2H5SncBAj5_YGamHorlZRBexoCsYEQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) , in case you want to refer to their documentation check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database).